# Structure Theorem for Finite Commutative Rings with unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-rings

The Structure Theorem for Finite Commutative Rings with unity
state that:

A finite commutative ring $R$ with multiplication identity
is isomorphic to a direct sum of local rings.

Suppose all the maximal ideals of $R$ are $M_1, M_2, ..., M_n$, 
and let $J$ be the Jacobson radical of $R$.
There exists a positive integer $k$ such that $J^k=0$.

There is an assertion in the proof which says that
$M_i$ is the unique maximal ideal such that 
$M_i^k\subseteq M_i$,
why?

---

The complete proof of the theorem see

- p. 9, lem. 9 in the thesis http://bfhaha.blogspot.tw/2014/06/thesis-classification-of-finite-rings.html
- p.95, thm. (VI.2) in the book "Finite rings with identity", Bernard R. McDonald
- p.40, thm. 3.1.4 in the article "Finite commutative rings and their applications", Gilberto Bini and Flamino Flamini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because maximal ideals are prime, and $M^k\subseteq P$ implies $M\subseteq P$ for a prime ideal $P$. If then $M$ is maximal, $M=P$.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I search the keyword "structure theorem..."
Most of the result proof the theorem use the advance notion,

Comment: @bfhaha It's usually stated for commutative Artinian rings.